# why some R codes have to be included in index.Rmd of Bookdown?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I downloaded bookdown-chinese at [Bookdown Chinese demo](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese) and removed all the `.Rmd` files except `index.Rmd`. When I built the book, why some R codes have to be included in `index.Rmd`,.

````
```{r}
 sessionInfo()
```
````

otherwise some errors would be prompted

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.105 \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment
                              {Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{...

Error: Failed to compile bookdown.tex. See bookdown.log for more info.
Please delete bookdown.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

in fact I edited a book without block R codes, and found I have to keep those R codes or changed any others R codes in `index.Rmd` in order build the book.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the R code that has to be kept? Having a quick look at the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/master/index.Rmd, I would guess that the YAML header at the top of the file is needed, but not the R code chunks.

Comment: In particular I think `documentclass: ctexbook` is probably important for compiling to PDF.

Comment: even when I changed to `{r echo=FALSE}', the book could not be built.  I  also kept `documentclass: ctexbook' in the YAML header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LaTeX command that is causing this error comes [from `preamble.tex`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/latex/preamble.tex#L40) and is defined in the LaTeX package `fancyvrb`. In [`template.tex`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/latex/template.tex#L117-L120) we see that `fancyvrb` is included only conditionally. And indeed, in `bookdown.tex` that is present when this error is produced, `fancyvrb` is not loaded.

If you are sure that you will not need R chunks in the future, you can simply remove the offending line from `preamble.tex`. If you might use R chunks in the future, have a look at [this PR](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/pull/23).

Comment: After I commented the line ` \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},formatcom=\xeCJKVerbAddon}', I made it.